# Best architecture for Android project "back-end" using service/dao layer pattern

Tags: java, android, rest, design-patterns, okhttp

Im trying to start a project using Spring Boot (REST) as the backend and Android as frontend. 
The problem is in the android project, because I want to use the Service - Controller pattern.

When I put the code destined to manage the http requests/response in other class, for example UserService, is outside the main thread and this can't manipulate the UI.

I was reading about "runonuithread" but the elements of the UI are not in the Service class... What can I do in this case? Add the elements to the class or manage the context inside the UserService?

This is for asyncronous calls.. But when I wan't to make synchronous calls this is neccesary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best scenario for using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Inside the activity, you can Subscribe to events, and from the Service, you will Publish the events.

**Activity/Fragment.java**

```
// ======= EventBus Subscribers =======
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED)
public void onEvent(ActionEvent event)
{
    // Maniupulate the UI directly
    titleTextView.setText(event.getTitle());
    messageTextView.setText(event.getMessage());
}
```

**ActionEvent.class**

```
// A Simple Class with the required properties
public class ActionEvent{

    private final String   title;
    private final String   message;

    public ActionEvent(String title, String message) {
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
    }

    ...
    // Getters and any other required stuff 
    ...
}
```

**Service.java**

```
// Appropriately compose and Post the event
ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent("Some Title", "Some Message");
EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
```